# Having trouble with printing out my output statement once without looping

Tags: java

This program is supposed to allow for the user to enter a student's name and score 10 times and output the average and the students' name that is below and greater than/equal to the average. When it gets to the point of the program where it outputs the students who have a score greater/less than the average, it does so in a loop instead of having only printing out all of the names once. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you`import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Grades{

   public static void main(String[] args){

   //create a keyboard representing the scanner
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   //define variables
      double [] score = new double[10];

      String [] name = new String[10];
      double average = 0.0, sum = 0.0, studentAverage = 0.0, highestScore = 0.0, lowestScore = 0.0;


      for(int i= 0; i < score.length; i++){  

         System.out.println("Enter the student's name: ");
         name[i] = console.next();
         System.out.println("Enter the student's score: ");
         score[i] = console.nextDouble();

         sum += score[i];

      }//end for loop

      //calculate average 
      average = sum/score.length;

      System.out.println("The average score is: " + average);


      int highestIndex = 0; 

      for(int i = 1; i < score.length; i++){

         if(score[highestIndex] < score[i]){

            highestIndex = i; 

         }

         if(score[i] < average){
            System.out.print("\nNames of students whose test scores are less than average: " + name[i]);
         }

         if(score[i] >= average){
            System.out.print("\nNames of students whose test scores are greater than or equal to average: " + name[i]);
         }


      }//end for loop

   }//end main

}//end clas
```

`

Comment: Well, you're calling `System.out.print("\nNames of students...")` _inside_ a loop, thus "it does so in a loop". You probably want to collect the names into lists first and then print them (and to print list elements you might want to use a loop as well, just call `System.out.print("\nNames of students...: "); for( String name : list ) { /*print the name here*/ }`.

Comment: I think you need to re-word what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your loop like that:

```
System.out.print("Names of students whose test scores are less than average: ");
for(int i = 1; i < score.length; i++){
    if(score[i] < average){
        System.out.print(name[i]);
    }
}

System.out.print("Names of students whose test scores are greater than or equal to average: ");
for(int i = 1; i < score.length; i++){
    if(score[i] >= average){
       System.out.print(name[i]);
    }
}
```

---

With your current code you print out the same line containing your text on each loop iteration. Using the modified code you just print it once, followed by the names.

Comment: Thank you very much